# Radeon -> VESA fallback since Bookworm update: "open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory"

Tags: debian, amd-graphics, radeon

I just updated my desktop to Bookworm. Now every time I launch a game, the colours are messed up and the screen goes like this: [image: 1]

It stays like this even after closing the game. The only solution is to close and reopen the session.

The only use case reproducing this is games because of the specific display mode they typically use. It doesn't happen when opening a GTK or Qt window. Only with those game windows that are either fixed resolution or full-screen (e.g.: wesnoth, SuperTux 2, emulated games in Mednaffe). How is this display mode called ?

Here's the graphic card:

```
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240/340 / Radeon 520]
```

I do have the following packages installed:

```
firmware-amd-graphics
xserver-xorg-video-all
libdrm-radeon1
```

Can't post full Xorg log file here. Here's the part that seems relevant:

```
[    27.453] (II) LoadModule: "ati"                                             
[    27.489] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so              
[    27.501] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"                         
[    27.501]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0                  
[    27.501]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver                                
[    27.501]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2                     
[    30.701] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"                                          
[    30.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so           
[    31.113] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"                      
[    31.117]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0                  
[    31.117]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver                                
[    31.117]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2                     
[    31.117] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"                                     
[    31.117] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so          
[    31.229] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"                 
[    31.229]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.21.1                  
[    31.229]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver                                
[    31.229]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2                     
[    31.229] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"                                           
[    31.229] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so            
[    31.337] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"                       
[    31.337]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0                   
[    31.337]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver                                
[    31.337]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2                     
[    31.337] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"                                            
[    31.337] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so               
[    31.373] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"                        
[    31.377]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0                   
[    31.377]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver                                
[    31.377]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2                     
[    31.377] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI/AMD Radeon chipsets:                   
[... Long list of chipsets ...]
[  2509.619] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  2509.619] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2509.619] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2509.623] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[  2509.623] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  2509.623] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  2509.623] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  2509.623] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2509.623] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2509.623] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2509.623] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2509.623]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 0.0.2
[  2509.623]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[  2509.623] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[  2509.623] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  2509.623] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2509.623] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2509.623] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2509.623] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2509.623]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 0.0.2
[  2509.623]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[  2509.623] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[  2509.623] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2509.623] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[  2509.623] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2509.623] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2509.623] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2509.623] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2509.623] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2509.623] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[  2509.623] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[  2509.623] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[  2509.623] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2509.623]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.0.0
[  2509.623]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[  2509.623] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[  2509.623] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[  2509.623] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[  2509.623] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2509.623]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.0.0
[  2509.623]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 16384 kB
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: AMD ATOMBIOS
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 15.42
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: (C) 1988-2010, Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: OLAND
[  2509.623] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 01.00
[  2509.643] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  2509.643] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  2509.643] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[  2509.643] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  2509.643] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  2509.643] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[  2509.643] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[  2509.643] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
```

Looks like radeon driver fails at some point and the system falls back on a default driver.

Is this correct and what can I do to fix this?

I don't see anything more in `.xsession-errors` or `syslog` when the graphical mayhem actually happens.

Edit:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240/340 / Radeon 520] driver: N/A
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 driver: X: loaded: vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon dri: swrast gpu: N/A
    resolution: 1920x1080
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 128 bits)
```

**Edit:** Bug reported on [Debian BTS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1040144).

Comment: Is `libdrm-radeon1` installed?

Comment: @IporSircer, yes it is. Question edited.